# How to use JUnit 5 with build.gradle.kts and Kotlin?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, junit5, gradle-kotlin-dsl

- Java version:    `java 10.0.1 2018-04-17`
- Kotlin version:  `1.2.41`
- Gradle version:  `4.7`

It will be even better if we could use **jigsaw module system**.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle) and a [sample project](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle) for using Gradle and JUnit 5.

If you want to use the Kotlin DSL you'll have to adapt it in the following way:

```
tasks.withType<Test>().configureEach {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

For Jigsaw, Gradle provides [experimental support](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/) and there's a [fork of the plugin](https://github.com/zyxist/chainsaw) that provides additional features.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any doc about `tasks.withType<Test>`?

Comment: Documentation for the Kotlin DSL is in progress and will be ready for the 1.0 release. Currently, your best bet is to look for existing projects that use it and check out the sample projects: https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 4):

Marc Philipp's answer works. Here is another approach:

```
val test: Test by tasks
test.useJUnitPlatform()
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more complete answer:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform() // Enables JUnit Platform (JUnit 5 + JUnit 4)
}

dependencies {
    // Aggregator dependency that also brings JUnit 5 parameterized tests etc.
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.10.0")
    // Include the Vintage engine to be able to run JUnit 4 tests as well
    // testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.10.0")
}
```